# How to define 2 default namespaces?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a library of custom contols and want them to be availavle without prefixes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your controls to be included in the default xmlns by adding this above the namespace:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "MyControls.MarkupExtensions")]
namespace MyControls.MarkupExtensions
{
...
}
```

This just adds them to the xmlns of the built-in controls rather than replacing it. You need to be careful when doing this that you don't step on names of any of the built-in controls.

Comment: I have following error: Error 1 Invalid XmlnsDeclaration occurs in assembly 'GenericTemplate'. XmlnsDeclaration references a namespace 'http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation' that is not in the assembly.

Comment: Try either using the default Microsoft one from my example or include a reference in your project to a Telerik assembly that declares that xml namespace.

Comment: It's included. I use it with 'xmlns:t="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"'. And yes I already tried it with Microsoft assembly: '[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation")]'

Comment: The second parameter in the attribute is the .NET namespace, not a second xml namespace.

Comment: ok now I get Error 1 Invalid XmlnsDeclaration occurs in assembly 'GenericTemplate'. XmlnsDeclaration references a namespace 'Telerik.Windows.Controls' that is not in the assembly. I verified that reference to this assembly is added to project.

Comment: Look at the example again - the .NET namespace in the attribute is the one defined directly below it. It could also be any other namespace in the assembly but in that case it makes more sense to put it elsewhere.

Comment: It could be? But why it's not working then? Namespace that I want to include is from the third-party assembly, I can't modify it.